# Is it safe in Python to assign a new value to variable from one thread while it is read from the another thread?

Tags: python, thread-safety, variable-assignment

I have a short script (below) where one thread is continuously checking the state of variable (if it is None or not). Is this approach safe without using a Lock, or is there any possibility that the checking thread could read "something strange between None and the reference on the new value"?

Thank you for answer, Martin

```
import time
import threading


class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = None

        self.e = threading.Event()
        self.e.set()

        self.checking_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.__check_if_not_none)
        self.checking_thread.start()

    def __check_if_not_none(self):
        while self.e.is_set():
            if self.data is not None:
                print("Ready")
            else:
                print("None")

    def prepare_data(self):
        data = []
        data.extend([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])  # Data preparing...
        self.data = data

    def quit(self):
        self.e.clear()
        self.checking_thread.join()
        print("Done")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = A()
    time.sleep(0.001)
    a.prepare_data()
    time.sleep(0.001)
    a.quit()
```